# cpp libcurl send zip file in http post call without using multipart\form-data

Tags: c++, upload, multipartform-data, libcurl, zip

We were using formdata in cpp libcurl to send data to our server using the following code:

```
curl_formadd(&form, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "file", CURLFORM_FILE, filePath.c_str(), CURLFORM_END);

curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, form);
```

But now our server has been updated to accept binary in http request body & not multipart\form-data. I have found curl command to attach zipfile without using multipart\form-data as follows

```
curl --request POST --data-binary "@file" $URL
```

but I cannot find its equivalent in cpp curl. Our requirement is to upload a zipfile in the http request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used POST_FIELDS to upload a zip file. Read the zip file in binary mode into a char pointer and passed it to like this:

```
    char * buffer;
    //read file into buffer
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)total);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, buffer);
```

Kindly correct me if I am wrong or suggest me for alternative

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `CURLOPT_READDATA` and `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` options.
Curl will repeatedly call `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` with whatever you pass as `CURLOPT_READDATA` as argument, until it returns 0 or `CURL_READFUNC_ABORT`.

By default, libcurl assumes your READFUNCTION reads from a filehandle.
The [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_READFUNCTION.html) shows the following example:

```
size_t read_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
  FILE *readhere = (FILE *)userdata;
  curl_off_t nread;

  /* copy as much data as possible into the 'ptr' buffer, but no more than
     'size' * 'nmemb' bytes! */
  size_t retcode = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, readhere);

  nread = (curl_off_t)retcode;

  fprintf(stderr, "*** We read %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T
          " bytes from file\n", nread);
  return retcode;
}

void setup(char *uploadthis)
{
  FILE *file = fopen("rb", uploadthis);
  CURLcode result;

  /* set callback to use */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_callback);

  /* pass in suitable argument to callback */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, uploadthis);

  result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
}
```

If you wanted to read from an in-memory buffer, your READFUNCTION would need to remember an offset somewhere and `memcpy` chunks every invocation until it reaches the end of the in-memory buffer.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. But, I have already tried this, not working.

Comment: And by "not working", what do you mean? Did the request not arrive? Was it not a POST? What did your code look like?

Comment: it did not arrive at the server

Comment: I am trying something like this:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=@"+filePath);

```

Comment: Where in the [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html) do you see this syntax supported? Also, that would still send a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` HTTP body. Are you sure that is what the API expects instead of a raw post with type `application/zip` or somesuch?

Comment: I saw similar code for [PHP](https://coderwall.com/p/fck2ta/how-to-send-files-via-curl-in-php). So, I tried the same for cpp

Comment: The [PHP implementation for POSTFIELDS](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/curl/interface.c#L2601) does many complicated things, so please keep to the libcurl documentation.